# Validation:Allow Numeric and Alphanumeric Pattern

Tags: jquery, regex

a textBox can contain values in format

DL-06-T-7405 (first two Alphabets then two Numbers then Alphabet and next four are Numbers) 
or
DL-06-TT-7405(first two Alphabets then two Numbers then two Alphabet and next four are Numbers) 
or
DL-06-TTT-7405(first two Alphabets then two Numbers then three Alphabet and next four are Numbers)

what i have done so far..

```
/^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{2}\w$/
```

but i can not make other cases
case 1: DL-06-TTT-7405
case 2: DL-06-TT-7405
case 3: DL-06-T-7405

how can i allow a textbox takeabove 3 cases only not other than this

Comment: You're missing the `-` characters in your Regex

Answer (score 1):

You may use a limiting quantifier `{1,3}` to match 1 to 3 occurrences, and add hyphens in between subpatterns:

```
^[A-Z]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[A-Z]{1,3}-[0-9]{4}$
                        ^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT2qvY/2)

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]{2}` - 2 uppercase ASCII letters
- `-` - a literal hyphen
- `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `-` - - hyphen
- `[A-Z]{1,3}` - 1 to 3 uppercase ASCII letters
- `-[0-9]{4}` - a hyphen, 4 digits
- `$` -  end of string.